# Ionic2 integrate custom iOS plugin with Alamofire framework as dependency

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, cocoapods, plugman

I have installed on my machine **cordova 7.0** & **Ionic 3.4.0**.
I made a custom plugin using **plugman** and it's structured as following:

```
src - ios & android folders with the native files
www - .js file
plugin.xml
package.json
```

Adding it to a Ionic 2 project (which is using cordova-ios 4.4.0) works fine, it's generated as expected and I can use it.

Now I need to add **Alamofire framework** as a dependency to my plugin. I need it to be **handled automatically** when a plugin is installed. I saw from the documentation ([How to add framework as dependency](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#framework)) that I should add:

```
<framework src="GoogleCloudMessaging" type="podspec" spec="~> 1.2.0" />
```

To the plugin.xml in the custom plugin. I added it but when I re-add the plugin into the ionic2 project it is not installing also the framework/pod.

I saw other topics related to mine but neither is helping me. I've tried everything, but I can't get it done.

Also, something weird with the  tag from the plugin.xml, according to the documentation is:

*Paired with type="podspec", this is the spec string for the CocoaPod you want to install (static library only). CocoaPod support only exists in **cordova-ios 4.3.0 and cordova-cli 6.4.0**. For your plugin, make sure you add the appropriate  tags and package.json dependencies to ensure backwards-compatible support.*

Isn't this quite strange, will it work for newer versions of cordova-ios?

Plugin - package.json content:

```
{
    "name": "cordova-plugin-requestService",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "*******",
    "private": true,
    "engines": {
        "cordovaDependencies": {
            "1.0.0":  { "cordova-ios": ">=4.4.0" }
        }
    }
}
```

plugin.xml content:

```
<!-- iOS -->
<platform name="ios">
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" version="^1.6.0" />
    <framework src="Alamofire" type="podspec" spec="~> 4.4.0" />
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="requestService">
            <param name="ios-package" value="requestService" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/ios/requestService.swift" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mainly solved the problems:

- Made a fresh starter of Ionic (with the latest versions of both cordova and ionic) - will migrate to the newer versions because of the incompatibilities between the cli's and project.
- Used  tag in the plugin.xml of the custom plugin
- Added platform - without the plugin (for now)
- Manually add the plugin (it will generate the podfile into the platform and other things)
  It will although throw an error because of the Alamofire. Add to the podfile use_frameworks! and it should be fine.

I also added the plugin automatically while triggering platform add ios

Unfortunately, cordova doesn't support yet this, but it's an open issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11893

You can use either a hook after add platform or https://github.com/blakgeek/cordova-plugin-cocoapods-support if you don't want to write it everytime, manually.